# Which Angular Material version should I install to be compatible with Angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Which Angular Material version should I install to be compatible with Angular4?

I have used below command to install angular Material on the top of Angular 4 project.

```
npm install @angular/materail 
npm install @angular/cdk
npm install @angular/animations
```

While I try to run the app I am getting below error.

```
/node_modules/@angular/cdk/observers/typings/observe-content.d.ts (33,22): Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me write the steps with more details to make it easier for beginners. Though the question is specific to version 4, the answer is applicable to all versions.

I had faced some issues with latest angular material version 9 as my angular version was 8. So I had to found the compatible version of angular material. Below are the steps I followed:

**1- Check the package.json file and notice the major version of angular modules. As shown below- core, compiler, common etc are having version as 8.2.14. Major version is 8.**

[image]

**2- Go to https://material.angular.io/ and on right hand top corner find the material version with same major version (8.2.3 in my case). Refer pic below.**

[image]

**3- Thus for angular v8.2.24, I found compartible angular material verison as 8.2.3. And it working with out any error.**

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to update your project to the latest version of angular. For stability, features and performance reasons. Also finding documentation/guides about such old version is a lot more difficult.

Besides that, if you want to install material for such an old angular version, you should use the `2.0.0-beta.12` version, which is compatible with angular 4:

```
npm install @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.12
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs

Answer (score 1):

You can choose a version between `2.0.0-beta.3` and `2.0.0-beta.12` depending on your minor angular version. Refer to [package.json](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/2.0.0-beta.12/package.json) file in [@angular/material](https://github.com/angular/components) repository to determine which one is more fittable to you.

Answer (score 0):

They have renamed as Angular/Components. May be you can try V2.0.0-beta.12 and check whether it helps.

npm install @angular/materail@2.0.0-beta.12
npm install @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12
npm install @angular/animations