# NullInjectorError: No provider for HighContrastModeDetector

Tags: angular, angular8

I am using Angular 8 for my project, using Node Version 10.15.3( had tried with other versions including latest 12.31.1). This works fine on MAC but while running on the Windows it stops on the browser with the error

```
NullInjectorError: "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatCommonModule -> HighContrastModeDetector]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatCommonModule -> HighContrastModeDetector]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HighContrastModeDetector!"
```

Is this related to my hardware (how does it is related)?

Comment: Seems like some version mismatch, since this server is providedIn: 'root':
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/a11y/high-contrast-mode/high-contrast-mode-detector.ts#L41
Are you sure all your angular packages have the same version that is required by your project?

Answer (score 24):

The issue is not related Node version. Its due to incompatible Angular Material and Angular versions. For angular 8, you need angular material version 8.2.3. Run below command from your project root directory.

```
npm i --save @angular/cdk@8.2.3 @angular/material@8.2.3
```

For steps to find out compatible angular and angular material version see ans to [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341559/which-angular-material-version-should-i-install-to-compatible-with-angular4)

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me on StackBlitz when I had a module from `@angular/material`, but not `import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';`.

In that case, the solution was to add the `BrowserModule`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `@angular/cdk` version was causing the error.

Setting it from `github:angular/cdk-builds` to `^8.1.4` on `package.json` and then running a `npm install` solved the problem

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case , incompatible versions of `@angular/cli` and `@angular/material` was causing the error.

to solve it :

try to upgrade node package modules to compatible versions in `package.json` and then run `npm install --save` command.