# Angular 10 NullInjectorError: No provider for HighContrastModeDetector

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 10 with these dependencies for my project:

```
"@angular/animations": "^10.0.2",
"@angular/cdk": "^10.0.1",
"@angular/common": "^10.0.2",
"@angular/compiler": "10.0.2",
"@angular/core": "^10.0.2",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
"@angular/forms": "^10.0.2",
"@angular/material": "^10.0.1",
"@angular/router": "^10.0.2",
```

The browser ends up with this error:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[A11yModule -> HighContrastModeDetector]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[A11yModule -> HighContrastModeDetector]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HighContrastModeDetector!
    at NullInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:52808:27)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63524:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63469:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63364:20)
    at resolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63524:24)
    at tryResolveToken (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63469:16)
    at StaticInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:63364:20)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:72986:29)
    at _createClass (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73037:29)
    at _createProviderInstance (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:73005:26)
```

Is it dependencies versions compatibility ?

Comment: This is most likely due to not adding the Angular service to the providers array in the module or not importing the module that provides that service.

Comment: You can refer the solution of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031570/nullinjectorerror-no-provider-for-highcontrastmodedetector

Comment: @DurgeshPal none of the answers helped me

Comment: @M1rwen did you find the solution to this problem? If so, can you please share it with us?